# chmod 400 command returning "No such file or directory" error. Trying to launch an instance through AWS

Tags: shell, filenames, tilde

CODE:

```
root@crane-linux:/home/crane/Downloads# sudo chmod 400 ~/home/crane/Downloads/mykey.pem
chmod: cannot access '/root/home/crane/Downloads/mykey.pem': No such file or directory
root@crane-linux:/home/crane/Downloads# ls
discord-0.0.1.deb  mykey.pem  torguard-latest-amd64.deb
root@crane-linux:/home/crane/Downloads#
```

Someone please help. I am having trouble with chmod not recognizing my file. I am using the provided tutorial to launch an instance through aws, but I keep getting a "No such file or directory" error, but as you can see when I did ls, the file does exist. Am I missing something here? Ive tried googling for the answer and tried entering the command in a bunch of different formats, but I keep getting the same problem.

No one said this would be easy....

P.S. I dont know how to make the quote box show up without the word "quote" like I see people do when they share something from the console. Its probably something simple IM just looking over but....

Comment: Did you notice that the path that `~` expands to is different from the one you list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tilde expansion is not pointing your current working directory, where the file is.  Use either an explicit or the correct tilde-expanded path:

```
chmod 400 /home/crane/Downloads/mykey.pem
```

or

```
chmod 400 ~crane/Downloads/mykey.pem
```

To expound on the tilde expansion a bit:

`~` means "my home directory".  If you're the root user, this is typically `/root`.

`~somebody` means "the home directory of the `somebody` user.  This is typically `/home/somebody` (or, on Macs, `/Users/somebody`).

When you, as root, use `~/home/somebody`, that expands your home directory, and becomes `/root/home/somebody`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Im a complete noob to linux so I guess that just makes me a complete noob. That ~ explanation really broke it down for me though. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Happy to help!  We all started somewhere.  Welcome to Linux, and to U&L!